# Diferenças entre os sotaques de Portugal e os da África

Tags: pronúncia, português-europeu

Eis uma dúvida que sempre tive enquanto falante brasileiro de Português.

Apesar da considerável diversidade entre os sotaques do Brasil, ainda assim os diversos sotaques no Brasil ainda parecem sensivelmente mais diferentes dos sotaques europeus (talvez incluindo até o Galego, que, julgo, só é ou era classificado como Espanhol por questões históricas e políticas) do que entre si.

Contudo, tenho a impressão de que os sotaques portugueses e os sotaques africanos sejam muito pouco diferentes, principalmente por eu não conseguir distingui-los.

Para ser explícito, eu estou me referindo mais à prosódia e à fonética do que à escolha de construções ou de vocabulário, as quais são, com certeza, fatores relevantes para traçar essas distinções.

Gostaria de saber se portugueses e se angolanos e moçambicanos aqui presentes percebem diferença entre os seus sotaques.

Se sim, vocês acham que seria possível fazer algum tipo de comparação da diferença entre os sotaque europeus e africanos com a diferença entre os sotaques europeus e brasileiros?  Ou da diferença entre os sotaque europeus e africanos com a diferença entre os sotaques africanos e brasileiros?  Ou, ainda, da diferença entre os sotaque brasileiros e africanos com a diferença entre os sotaques europeus e brasileiros?

Comment: Esta pergunta está um pouco confusa. O título é "diferença entre os sotaques de Portugal e de África", o que já de si é uma pergunta muito ampla (há muitos sotaques em Portugal e em África), mas depois pareces querer uma caracterização de **todos** os sotaques (incluindo os vários americanos).

Comment: @Artefacto Primeiramente, pergunto se os falantes respectivos percebem diferença. Segundamente, em caso positivo, quis pedir que tentassem caracterizar a(s) diferença(s) percebida(s).  Devo editar a pergunta?

Comment: @Artefacto hipoteticamente e apenas a título de ilustração, eu poderia ser lisboeta, nunca ter vindo ao Brasil e não perceber diferença entre os sotaques de São Paulo e Rio de Janeiro, apesar de ela ser clara o suficiente para cariocas e paulista (e paulistanos) saberem pontuá-la.

Answer (score 6):

Creio que há uma grande variedade de sotaques no português africano. Para começar, são cinco países distantes entre si; e mesmo dentro de cada país o sotaque varia. Dito isto, há um tipo de sotaque que eu identifico como africano, e que na minha perceção varia consoante o falante entre o praticamente igual ao meu sotaque, comum na região de Lisboa, e o muito diferente, mas não próximo dos sotaques do Brasil.

Agora a perceção de diferenças entre sotaques depende muito da exposição que uma pessoa teve. Eu tenho pouca exposição a sotaques africanos, e consigo apenas ver se um africano tem um sotaque praticamente igual ao meu, parecido, um bocadinho diferente, muito diferente, etc. E ao ouvir um africano, não sei dizer de que país ele é. Apresento abaixo vários exemplos. Atenção que são todos de apresentadores de televisão, políticos, artistas e pessoas geralmente com instrução acima da média, e portanto poderão não ser representativas do leque dos sotaques africanos. Nos meu comentários, classifico os sotaques por comparação com o meu.

> [Entrevista do guineense Domingos Simões Pereira, secretário da CPLP, à televisão moçambicana em 2012.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41THnmzFgaw) O sotaque do locutor, que eu presumo moçambicano, não se distingue do que se ouve na região de Lisboa; o do guineense Domingo Pereira tem um não sei quê muito subtil de africano.
>
> [Entrevista do Presidente da Guiné-Bissau João Mário Vaz à televisão cabo-verdiana em 2014.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFHNFk02SRw)  A primeira apresentadora cabo-verdiana tem um sotaque do mesmo tipo que o meu. O presidente guineense tem um não sei quê de diferente, e a entrevistadora é quem o sotaque mais diferente, ainda assim muito ligeiro.
>
> [Filhos do Presidente de Angola](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cACR7Et4z_4). O filho tem um sotaque ligeiramente pronunciado; a filha passava mais ou menos despercebida em Lisboa.
>
> [Dois angolanos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2paC1i-lc8) com sotaques mais pronunciado. A seguir ao minuto 1’20’’ ouve-se uma entoação muito africana para os meus ouvidos: «sou produtor, tenho muitas facetas».

Entre as coisas que fazem os sotaques africanos mais próximos dos de Portugal que do Brasil estão os sons. Os sons consoantes são os mesmos que em Portugal. O ***l*** no fim de palavra é mesmo ***l*** (*mal* é diferente de *mau*) e não têm os ***dji*** e ***tchi*** com que muitos falantes brasileiros pronunciam *cida**de*** e ***ti**a*. Têm também a tendência típica do português europeu de fechar e reduzir vogais átonas.

A *Gramática do Português* da Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian (2013) dedica um capítulo ao português de Angola e de Moçambique. Explica que apenas uma pequena minoria da população fala o português como primeira língua (11% em Moçambique em 2007; p. 160), e que a fonologia das línguas bantas maternas tende a se fazer sentir naqueles que falam o português como segunda língua, especialmente nos menos instruídos (pp. 163-4).

Nas línguas bantas maternas predomina a sílaba constituída por consoante + vogal, e este padrão reflete-se na fala do português pelo acrescento de vogais onde no português europeu não existem: /i/ em Moçambique e /e/ em Angola no fim de palavra terminada por consoante (*beber* é pronunciado /beberi/ ou /bebere/); separação de encontros consonantais em princípio de sílaba com uma cópia da vogal tónica (*patrão* é pronunciado /patarão/, *flor*, /folor/); e evitando a supressão do *e* átono típica da pronúncia de muitas palavras no português europeu (*querido* pronunciado /kridu/ em Portugal, mas  /kiridu/ em Moçambique e /kerido/ em Angola).

Note-se que eu não notei estes aspetos nos vídeos que linkei. No útlimo vídeo, o apresentador pronuncia *single* como *singuele*, mas pareceu-me que ele estava a exagerar, pois não pronunciava assim as outras palavras. Imagino que as pessoas nestes vídeos sejam das que têm o português como língua materna.

Comment: @Artefacto Vou ver.

Comment: Essa pergunta me passou despercebida na época em que foi postada.  A resposta esclarece algumas dúvidas minhas.  +1.